# Looking for using visibility as an output in an adaptive card

Tags: adaptive-cards

Instead of using a choiceset, I would like to use several Action.ToggleVisibility.
But to do so, in my Action.submit, I need to put the value of the visibilty of each Action.ToggleVisibility.

Following the idea I want to put in place:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "version": "1.3",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "How are you ?",
            "weight": "Bolder",
            "size": "Medium",
            "horizontalAlignment": "Center"
        },
        {
            "type": "ColumnSet",
            "columns": [
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "width": "stretch",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "ActionSet",
                            "actions": [
                                {
                                    "type": "Action.ToggleVisibility",
                                    "title": ":(",
                                    "targetElements": [
                                        "Bad",
                                        "Good",
                                        "VeryGood"
                                    ],
                                    "data": {
                                        "button": "VeryBad"
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            "id": "VeryBad"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "width": "stretch",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "ActionSet",
                            "actions": [
                                {
                                    "type": "Action.ToggleVisibility",
                                    "title": ":/",
                                    "targetElements": [
                                        "VeryBad",
                                        "Good",
                                        "VeryGood"
                                    ],
                                    "data": {
                                        "button": "Bad"
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            "id": "Bad"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "width": "stretch",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "ActionSet",
                            "actions": [
                                {
                                    "type": "Action.ToggleVisibility",
                                    "title": ":)",
                                    "targetElements": [
                                        "VeryBad",
                                        "Bad",
                                        "VeryGood"
                                    ]
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            "id": "Good"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "width": "stretch",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "ActionSet",
                            "actions": [
                                {
                                    "type": "Action.ToggleVisibility",
                                    "title": ":D",
                                    "targetElements": [
                                        "VeryBad",
                                        "Bad",
                                        "Good"
                                    ]
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            "id": "VeryGood"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "actions": [
        {
            "type": "Action.Submit",
            "title": "Send"
        }
    ]
}
```

Does anyone know if this is possible in an adaptive card ? And if so how can I do that ?

Comment: Pretty interesting idea, afaik you cant get the visibility in the response but depending on where you use that card you can access the full card and could parse it yourself...however feels as if your within ms teams / bot framework right?

Comment: Thanks fo your answer ! Yes the idea is to send this card on Teams using Power Automate... Could it be possible even so ?